# Running query on csv file through flask

Tags: rest, csv, flask

I am not a programmer and trying to learn and get this working for an assignment. I have a need to use flask rest API to search and pull data from the CSV file to the page. The goal is to have user insert the string on /logcheck/<user_input>, this will trigger a search for <user_input> on csv file and pull the entire rows of data and return the result.

The sample of CSV, and location on
/home/logs/
And the sample shot of the CSV file content as follows:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQpDb.png

Flask code as follow:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
import sys
from flask import Flask, request, send_file, jsonify, Response, render_template
from flask.helpers import make_response

csv_file = csv.reader(open('/home/logs/containerlogs.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")


@app.route('/logcheck/<user_input>', methods=['GET'])
def logcheck(user_input):
    healthy = request.form ['healthy']
    unhealthy = request.form ['unhealthy']
if user_input not healthy or not unhealthy:
    return make_response("Please try again./n Only word /logcheck/healthy or logcheck/unhealthy)
else:
    for row in csv_file:
        if user_input == row[0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5]:
            return make_response (print (row))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv, json
from flask import Flask, make_response

csv_rows = []
with open('containerlogs.csv', "r") as o:
    csv_file = csv.reader(o, delimiter=",")
    for row in csv_file:
        csv_rows.append(row)
    o.close()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/logcheck/<user_input>', methods=['GET'])
def logcheck(user_input):
    #healthy = request.form ['healthy']     # Why request.form?
    #unhealthy = request.form ['unhealthy'] # If requests.form it works only when methods=['POST'].
    #if user_input not healthy or not unhealthy:
    if user_input != 'healthy' and user_input != 'unhealthy':
        return make_response("Please try again./n Only word /logcheck/healthy or logcheck/unhealthy")
    else:
        rows = '' #[]
        for row in csv_rows:
            if user_input in row:
                #rows.append(row)
                rows += ', '.join(row) + '<br>'
        return make_response (rows) #json.dumps (rows)

app.run("0.0.0.0", 8080)
```

Comment: Hi Lima. Thank you. The above code work, however, the results get thrown as a single line on the page. Can each of the results get shown line by line on the page?

Comment: Some places suggest adding the '/n' but to my luck, it is not working. As you can see I have very limited knowledge of programming. Below are the output result, there is no line break from each result. Is there a way to add a line break at the end of each  "]," or another easier way so the result gets printed line by line? Thanks in advance

[["Mon Nov 1 21:38:11 NZDT 2021", "webserver", "2.32%", "0.90%", "running", "healthy"], ["Mon Nov 1 21:38:21 NZDT 2021", "webserver", "0.00%", "0.84%", "running", "healthy"],

Comment: I edited, now is OK?